# Shortcut to unindent in Powerpoint

Tags: ms-office

In many applications `shift-tab` will unindent: but it just indents further on `powerpoint`.  What is the shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my external keyboard (on macbook pro) were the culprit: entering `shift-tab` does work when pressed directly on the mbpro itself.  I have not noticed this shortcoming in other applications so wondering if there were some low-level keycodes being captured by PowerPoint - i.e. not properly using the standard Mac keyboard interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

⇧⇥ is the shortcut for unindent, but you need to select the paragraph to unindent. If you have no selection, or just a word, the shortcut doesn't work.